# publish a event on FB wall

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to publish on the wall.It gives me a popup "OK Success" but cant find it on the wall

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({
                appId: '18********',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            function wallpost(message, title, link, desc, picture, name, uid) {
                var kime = '/' + uid + '/feed';
                FB.api(kime, 'post', {
                    message: message,
                    name: 'Blabla..',
                    link: link,
                    picture: picture,
                    caption: title,
                    action_links: [{
                        text: 'BlablablanaFinally..',
                        href: 'http://thomasblog.somee.com/'
                    }],
                    description: desc
                }, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert(name + ' Success');
                    } else {
                        alert(name + ' Fail');
                    }
                });
            }


            function sharex() {
                wallpost('checking', "postingtowall", 'http://thomasblog.somee.com/', 'Hello World.', 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.gif', ' Ok ', 'me');
            }

    </script>
<p>
           <a href="#" onclick="sharex();">Publish to Wall</a>
        </p>
```

Please help me publish this on my FB wall. On click of the link, it pops a dialog "Ok Success". But I dont see the post on my wall.

Thanks
Sun

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert(name + ' Success');
                } else {
                    alert(name + ' Fail');
                }
```

Also, check the response status code and the response string you're getting.

Comment: Yes I was able to fix it..But one more question: How do I post an event on FB wall. Suppose If I am creating a simple calendar event using asp.net, now how I post the event to my FB wall

Comment: I'm an iOS dev, so I don't know the specifics.  But it only involves making a request with the Graph API.  For example to post to the wall of the currently logged-in user use the endpoint "h t t p s://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"  and send a POST request with appropriate values.  (Just remove the spaces from "https".  Couldn't get it to display properly without spaces.)